# How to change bundle start level in glassfish 3.1.2 equinox?

Tags: osgi, glassfish-3, equinox

I want to change the start level for a bundle in my glassfish. I used equinox as osgi runtime.

I changed the configuration file glassfish\config\osgi.properties and add the folowing line:

osgi.bundles=bundlesymbolicname@5:start

When I connect via telnet and search the bundle with "lb bundleid" I see in the level column 1 instead of 5.

Can anyone help me? What is the problem with my configuration?

Thanks Marco.

Answer (score 1):

You can change in in ${GF_HONE}/glassfish/config/osgi.properties, by update the below item:

```
# What should be the initial start level of framework. 
# For performance reason, initially we set the start level to 1 so that no optional
# bundles can get activated while server is still starting. Once server is started,
# the framework's start level is set to whatever is configured in glassfish.osgi.start.level.final property.
org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning=1

# Set bundle start level to be same or less than that of framework, 
# otherwise HK2 installed bundles won't be activated.
# See issue #5934
felix.startlevel.bundle=1
```